# Media query problem: font size not changing on phones

Tags: html, media-queries, font-size

I am doing a page that font size 16px for computer desktop and 36px for small device such as iphone and other small phones. I set the

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

in the head area and use style:

```
@media (min-width:320px) { 
    /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */   
    p.Description {
        font-size: 36px;
    }
}

@media (min-width:481px) {
    /* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */ 
    p.Description {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

@media (min-width:641px) {
    /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, landscape e-readers, landscape 800x480 or 854x480 phones */ 
    p.Description {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

@media (min-width:961px) { 
    /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops and desktops */ 
    p.Description {
        font-size: 16px; 
    }
}

@media (min-width:1025px) {
    /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ 
    p.Description {
        font-size: 26px; 
    }
}

@media (min-width:1281px) { 
    /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ 
    p.Description {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

Now I have problems - it works well on computer but not on iPhones.

Can you guys help me? What is wrong with it?

Comment: Did you tried @media  only screen and (max-width:  481px){ font-size: 36px } ?

Comment: Side note: Wouldn't it be better to have the smallest rule like `max-width:481px` (instead of `min-width:320px`) so as to target everything-smaller-than-481px ?

Comment: thank you,
mohammad taheri
 I have tried your code, it make no defferent. the font size changed on computer when I change the size in style code. When I change the font size for iphone just to see it works or not, it did not change, it just the same size of on the computer.

Comment: Kalnode: I had tried anything I could think of, that you said max-width and min-width. it seems no help. the font size only works on computer, not on iphone. It is the same font size on the computer which is too small to read on iphone.

Comment: Sorry my bad. You should try this: @media only screen and (max-width: 481px){ p.Description { font-size: 36px }}. For reference read this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.php

Comment: mohammad taheri, I put your code there, and it still not working, the text on iphone is not 36 that I wanted. It is 16px same on the computer.

Comment: @谁的明天 I have given answer. Try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply **remove** the below media-query:-

```
@media (min-width:320px) { 
    /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */   
    p.Description {
        font-size: 36px;
    }
}
```

And instead of this, **Add** this:-

```
    p.Description {
        font-size: 36px;
    }
```

This will set the **font-size to 36px**. And as **screen width reaches 481px**, then due to **other media query the font-size become 16px**.

Overall the updated code is:-

```
/* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */ 
p.Description {
  font-size: 36px;
}

@media (min-width:481px) {
   /* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */ 
    p.Description {
       font-size: 16px;
    }
}

@media (min-width:641px) {
    /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, landscape e-readers, landscape 800x480 or 854x480 phones */ 
    p.Description {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

@media (min-width:961px) { 
    /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops and desktops */ 
    p.Description {
        font-size: 16px; 
    }
}

@media (min-width:1025px) {
    /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ 
    p.Description {
        font-size: 26px; 
    }
}

@media (min-width:1281px) { 
    /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ 
    p.Description {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try your method, it make no difference. The code itself is not wrong, it just not working on mobile, only on desktop computer. It seems did not target the mobile, only computer.

Comment: @谁的明天 Are you sure, your iphone screen / mobile screen is lesser than 481px?

Comment: I tried it on my iPhone 11 it view port size :414 x 896

Comment: @谁的明天 then CSS is totally ok. Put html on Question

Comment: something missing html? what to look?

Comment: Just add your html also in the code snippet in the question

Comment: yes you are right. I have just removed some html code from the first few lines, and copy paste 
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> into it and the font size is the way I want it to be. Thank you for pointing a direction for me to resolve this issue.

Comment: @谁的明天 if you seem the answer valuable, mark this correct for future visitors.